# Maintaining focus or first responder state of NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, nsoutlineview

I have a subclass of an NSOutline.  When it loses focus, the disclosure triangle of a selected row changes from its inverted template form (white) back to black.  I don't want this to happen:  I want the appearance of a selected row to stay the same, as in XCode or Mail.

I've tried intercepting firstResponder-based messages in the NSOutlineView subclass, as well in my custom rowViews, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my subclass of NSTableRowView, doing the following works:

```
- (BOOL)isEmphasized {

    return YES;
}
```